# How to make a React component not update when I refresh the page?

Tags: reactjs, refresh

So I'm making a quiz-like app and in my component I have a number of questions and a timer.
I'd like to know how I should make it that when I refresh the page, the timer will stay the same and I will still be at the same question I had to answer.

Comment: You need to persist the data at backend or frontend. At frontend, it maybe stored in LocalStorage which will persist even after the page refreshes. After refreshing the page, you need to read it back from the storage (when component mounts) and set it to react / redux (etc.) state.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't

Long answer: When you refresh the page, your component will unmount and mount again. You can't prevent this. If you want to store a state, you need to make it persistent. One common way of doing this is storing the state variable to the `localStorage`

Example:

```
localStorage.setItem('timer',timer)
localStorage.getItem('timer')
```

There is a nice [article](https://dev.to/akhilaariyachandra/persistent-state-in-react-f50) about this, see if it helps